# Ratio between positive and negative examples in a training problem

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-models, prediction, binary-data

When training a 0/1 classifier, what should be the ratio of positive to negative, how to decide the ratio between them based on the classifier I use and the data set under analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you want the number/frequency of instances in each class to be equal or as close to equal as possible. In the extreme situation where you have a lop sided number of instances for the classes, this situation is called, class imbalance, and it presents problems for some methods of learning predictive models, especially probability based predictive models.

Some methods to dealing with class imbalance may be to oversample the class with the smaller number of instances, undersample the class with the larger number of instances, or use boosting techniques.